# React js how to inject javascript in jsx object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I don't want to display `"no file selected"` on input file and replacing with another button.

```
var form = React.createClass({
   render : function(){
        var fileStyle = { display : none };
        return (
         <form>
            <input id="file" type="file" style={fileStyle}>
            <button onClick={ /* how to perform click on file*/ }> click to add image</button>
         </form>
        );
    }
});
```

I want when I click button then input file is perform click.

How to accomplish this within React js?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

- Assign a ref to a field
- Find corresponding dom node using `findDOMNode` and the ref
- Trigger click manually.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/ozWzgr).

```
const { Component } = React
const { render, findDOMNode } = ReactDOM

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.trigger = this.trigger.bind(this)
  }

  trigger() {
    findDOMNode(this.file).click()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" ref={file => this.file = file} style={{
            display: 'none'
          }} />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.trigger}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to include javascript statements in JSX

```
import React from 'react';

const person = () => {
    return <p>I have {Math.floor(Math.random()*30)} years of experience.</p>
}

export default person;
```

This example shows a React component using function.